# Download a file after autentication, of five options. Selenium

Tags: selenium

I am trying to download a file after a login, so far the program enters the url and enters the user data and password, the problem is when I try to download the file of the five available options (I need the last one). The problem is that even if it does not mark any error the program does not download the file.
just does nothing.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Driverchrome\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/download/external/options/LANDSAT_8_C1/LC80260472019253LGN00/INVSVC/")

login=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[input/@class='button pageButton']")
login.click()
time.sleep(2)

usuario=driver.find_element_by_name("username")
usuario.send_keys("Alex")

contrasena=driver.find_element_by_name("password")
contrasena.send_keys("micontraseña")
contrasena.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

descargar=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Downl")
descargar.click()
```

I have tried different ways to call the download button, but none worked for me.
the code of the download button is:

```
<input type="button" class="button inlineButton" title="Download this Product" onclick="window.location='https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/download/12864/LC80260472019253LGN00/STANDARD/INVSVC'" value="Download">
```

It is important to say that the other download buttons have a similar code except for the download link

Comment: To make Selenium better at finding elements, I would suggest using ID's. Elements targeted by Selenium should have a unique ID associated. Then you can simply find the element with the ID.

Comment: Hi, the ID is <div id="optionsPage">, but it includes all the buttons, so I don't know how to specify that download the file of last button

Comment: I was suggesting adding an new id on the button itself. Not the parent. If you want to only have the ID on the parent you can achieve this with Xpath: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: Thanks bro you are awesome!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has answered in comments. If possible you could add an Id to the button you want to find and then find it with selenium using that unique id.

If you don't want or can't add the Id, you can use an XPath to find the last button of an element. More information on Xpath here: [W3School XPath](http://%20w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)